# TensorFlow: critical graph operations assigned to cpu rather than gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have implemented a TensorFlow DNN model (2 hidden layers with elu activation functions trained on MNIST) as a Python class in order to wrap TF calls within another library with its own optimization routines and tools.

When running some tests on a TeslaK20 I noticed that the GPU was being used at 4% of the total capacity. Therefore I looked a bit more closely to the log-device-placement and figured that all critical operations like `MatMul`, `Sum`, `Add`, `Mean` etc were being assigned to the CPU.

The first thing that came to mind was that it was because I was using `dtype=float64`, therefore I switched to `dtype=float32`. While a lot more operations were assigned to GPU, still a good number were assigned to the CPU, like `Mean`, `gradient/Mean_grad/Prod`, `gradient/Mean`.

So here comes my first question (I'm linking a working code example at the end),

1) why would that be? I have written different TF models that consist of simple tensor multiplications and reductions and they run fully on GPU as long as I use single precision.

So here comes the second question,

2) why does TF assign the graph to different devices depending on the data type? I understand that not all kernels are implemented for GPU but I would have thought that things like `MatMul` could run on GPU for both single and double precision.

3) Could the fact that the model is wrapped within a Python class have an effect? I do not think this is the case because as I said, it did not happen for other models wrapped similarly but that were simpler.

4) What sort of steps can I take to run the model fully on a GPU?

Here is a full working example of my code that I have isolated from my library

https://gist.github.com/smcantab/8ecb679150a327738102 .

If you run it and look at the output you'll see how different parts of the graph have been assigned to different devices. To see how this changes with types and devices change `dtype` and `device` within `main()` at the end of the example. Note that if I set `allow_soft_placement=False` the graph fails to initialize.

Any word of advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: Looks like support for double in matmul is turned off [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/matmul_op.cc#L226). Seems weird, it's calling CuBLAS which has support for double. There is also a number of operations that don't have GPU implementations for any data-type

Comment: Bottom line -- a bunch of ops are not implemented on GPU. One strategy is to restructure computation to use more GPU-compatible ops and file github issues for the rest to track community progress. Enabling double support for matmul seems like a low-hanging fruit

Comment: try to add `(use_gpu=True, force_gpu=True)` to your session and see where it fails when constructing the graph.

Comment: Thanks Yaroslav, I raised an issue here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1140

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Yaroslav noted:  [Mean, in particular, was not yet implemented for GPU](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/reduction_ops_mean.cc), but it is now available so these operations should run on the GPU with the latest TensorFlow.  (as per the DEVICE_GPU registration at that link)

Prior to availability of mean, the status of this was:

(a)  You can implement mean by hand, because `reduce_sum` [is available on GPU](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/reduction_ops_sum.cc).

(b)  I've re-pinged someone to see if there's an easy way to add the GPU support, but we'll see.

Re `float64` on GPU, someone opened an issue three days ago with a patch for [supporting float64 reductions on GPU](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/1089).  Currently being reviewed and tested.

No, it doesn't matter if it's wrapped in Python - it's really just about whether a kernel has been defined for it to execute on the GPU or not.  In many cases, the answer to "why is X supported on GPU by Y not?" comes down to whether or not there's been demand for Y to run on the GPU.  The answer for float64 is simpler:  float32 is a lot faster, so in most cases, people work to make their models work in float32 when possible because it gives all-around speed benefits.

Comment: ok thanks. I'll do the following then: 1) rewrite as many ops as I can using GPU supported ops 2) raise an issue on github to extend support to doubles. I looked at the `reduce_sum` issue that you pointed to and it seems that all was done was adding `REGISTER_GPU_KERNELS(double)` in the kernels. I understand that one then has to write tests, but is this really all that needs to be done?

Comment: Depends on the op.  Some of them probably have type-specific optimization;  I'm not sure what the case is for the matrix multiply.  The other case is that every op takes space in binaries, and so there's some desire to only include ops that are actually being used to avoid unnecessary bloat.  People asking for it is evidence that the bloat is worth it. :)

Comment: I think it should "just work" now based on the [current tensorflow op code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/reduction_ops_mean.cc).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the graphics cards like the GTX 980, 1080, etc are stripped of the double precision floating point hardware units. Since these are much cheaper and therefore more ubiquitous than the Newer Tesla Units (which have FP64 double precision hardware), doing double precision calculations on the graphics cards is very slow compared to single precision. FP64 calculations on a GPU seem to be about 32 X slower than FP32 on a GPU without the FP64 hardware. I believe this is why the FP32 calculations tend to be set up for the GPU while FP64 for the CPU (which is faster in most systems.) Hopefully in the future, the frameworks will test the GPU capabilities at runtime to decide where to assign the FP64 calculations.